# pyqtgraph: DateAxisItem does not show when inverted

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

My DateAxisItem axis is not displayed when calling the `invertY()` function. To be precise the values that we would normally see on the axis disappears.
It does work if it's a normal AxisItem or if we don't call invertY() but I want it inverted.
Here is my code example :

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])
plot = pg.plot()
x = pg.AxisItem(orientation="top")
y = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation="left")
plot.getPlotItem().hideAxis("bottom")
plot.getPlotItem().setAxisItems({"top": x, "left": y})
plot.getPlotItem().getViewBox().invertY(True)
app.exec_()
```

Is it a bug or did I do something wrong ?

**Edit** : It is indeed a bug and I posted an [issue](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1635). If someone has a quick fix for now I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quick fix by overriding the `tickValues` method and inverting the parameters like so :

`MyDateAxisItem.py` :

```
from pyqtgraph import DateAxisItem

class MyDateAxisItem(DateAxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickValues(self, minVal, maxVal, size):
        return super().tickValues(maxVal, minVal, size)
```